# The events are independent iff $P(B_{1}\cap \dots \cap B_{n})=P(B_{1}) \cdots P(B_{n})$

Tags: probability

I want to prove that the events $A_{1}, \dots, A_{n}$ are independent iff

$$P(B_{1}\cap \dots \cap B_{n})=P(B_{1}) \cdots P(B_{n})$$

for $B_{i}=A_{i}$ or $B_{i}=A_{i}^{c}$

Well, I feel that for the case where $B_{i}=A_{i}$ is something obvious by definition, what would it take to put it in the proof, while for the other case, let $A_{1}, \dots, A_{n}$ independent events, note that:

\begin{align*}
  P(A_{1}^{c} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n}^{c}) &= 1-P(A_{1} \cup \cdots \cup A_{n}) \\
   &= 1-[P(A_{1})+ \cdots-P(A_{1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n} )] \\
   &= 1-P(A_{1})- \cdots+P(A_{1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n} ) \\
   &=(1-P(A_{1}))(1-P(A_{2})) \cdots (1-P(A_{n}))
\end{align*}

And from the last equality one would have, is this a valid reasoning?

The reverse side, I don't know how to give an argument for the first case, while for the second we could assume that $A_{1}^{c}, \dots, A_{n}^{c}$ are independent events, and

\begin{align*}
  P(A_{1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n}) &= P(A_{1}) + \cdots +P(A_{n}) - P(A_{1} \cup \cdots \cup A_{n}) \\
   &=P(A_{1}) + \cdots +P(A_{n}) -1+ P(A_{1}^{c}) \cdots P(A_{n}^{c})   \\
   &= P(A_{1}) \cdots P(A_{1}) 
\end{align*}

Is this valid again?

It would be of great help to receive a suggestion for the case that was not possible for me, thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of independence you are using? Because that which you are trying to prove is the definition of independence as I know it.

Comment: There are not just two cases.  You want your equation to be true for all $2^n$ cases where each $B_i$ is either $A_i$ or $A_i^c$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator : Wrloord wishes to demonstrate that if $n$ events are mutually independent then any combination of those events or their complements are also mutually independent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp now I understand

Comment: As a simple case, note that $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) + P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3^c) = P A_1 P A_2$.

Comment: Pick a number uniformly at random from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. Let $B_1$ be the number is prime; let $B_2$ be the same as $B_1$; let $B_3$ be the number is even. Then $P(B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3)=P(B_1)P(B_2)P(B_3)=1/8$, but clearly the events are not pairwise independent.

Comment: How's it going, Wrl?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I find it somewhat difficult to see even the case where it is not the complement, i.e. $A_{i}=B_{i}$ because it seems to be easy to see by definition.

Comment: Do you not understand my example, Wrl? Is there some particular difficulty I could engage with?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has disengaged.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to merely show that all complements are mutually independent, but rather that *any* selection of $k$ among the $n$ events and the complements of the remaining $n-k$ events have that property ; for any $k\in[[0..n]]$.

Hint:  Make arguments from symmetry and mathematical induction.